# Core Data - NSPredicate - Finding properties that equal 0 but are not Null

Tags: iphone, core-data, nspredicate

There's no way this question hasn't been asked before but I cannot find a clear answer anywhere.

I have Core Data entities that have optional 'Integer 32' attributes. I'm trying to setup a predicate to retrieve all objects where that attribute equals zero but is not null.

```
attributes.power == nil AND attributes.power == 0
```

That's not doing the job. This is returning no results. Removing the first half of the compound predicate returns zeros and nulls.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I un-fixed the operators in your question, since without the mistake the accepted answer doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This may be a simple typo, but I believe you want the predicate

```
attributes.power != nil AND attributes.power == 0
```

Comment: Whoops, yeah, just a typo in my question. Thanks for catching that. I've edited my question.

Comment: While this wasn't my problem this time (I had a total bone-head moment...), this DOES in fact work as expected. Thanks for posting ^_^

Comment: @dontGoPlastic, glad I could help by getting you to look a the code again. I call this Wark's Law: Any sufficiently complex problem in software development will be solved by the asker immediately upon asking for help.

Comment: Yes, that is why I keep around a Wilson soccer ball with a face drawn on it ala Tom Hanks in Castaway. If I get stuck, I just try to explain the problem to Wilson and suddenly I find the answer.

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you try using optional 'String' attributes instead and then converting them to integers.
 Alternatively, you can use a '-1' to indicate invalid values and put that as the default value of your attribute.

Comment: you probably don't want to use strings to store integers, even if its convenient to have the optional attribute.  I would argue that the extra bugs introduced by the conversion step is alarming enough.

Comment: I agree that String attributes may not be a good solution here. Conversions if managed properly using an abstraction layer can provide for a convenient and flexible optional attribute. But I still do agree with you that you can avoid it.